# Where is the latest revision of subsonic 3?

Tags: subsonic

When I click the big download button at

http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0

I don't know what version I'm getting. On the download panel there are 3 additional versions listed for download. Which is the most recent, the default or 3.0.0.3?

And does the big download button get me everything for that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On GitHub, when you click the "Download" button (not the tab), you will download the latest revision (known as the `master` branch in Git) in the repository. This is potentially untested code and should be avoided in production environments.

To answer your question specifically, you should download `3.0.0.3` unless you want potentially untested, beta-quality code.

For more reliable information, check the [SubSonic Download page](http://subsonicproject.com/Download).